# What is better to use to store items for a catalog app? A SQL database or another kind of data structure?

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm developing a catalogue app ("kind of") for a card-collection. My idea was to show the items in a `RecyclerView` with `CardViews`. I thought about storing everything in a `SQL database`. My problem here is that I don't know how to "prepare" the in-app database, like: you install the app and you have the catalog. The item needs 5 parameters (two strings, two int and an image). 
My next level will be to implement everything with an online database. Anyway, at the moment my question is: Is a SQL databse a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Green Dao Framework](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/)

greenDAO Android ORMgreenDAO is an open source Android ORM making development for SQLite databases fun again. It relieves developers from dealing with low-level database requirements while saving development time. SQLite is an awesome embedded relational database. Still, writing SQL and parsing query results are quite tedious and time-consuming tasks. greenDAO frees you from these by mapping Java objects to database tables (called ORM, “object/relational mapping”). This way you can store, update, delete, and query for Java objects using a simple object oriented API.

Comment: So it is like to have a SQL Database that contains java objects?

Comment: Yes, and also is a relational database. You can go to greenDAO docks and see all the examples there.

Comment: Okay I will. My last question is: to add something like 4250 items, shall I add them manually in the code?

Comment: what do you think about Firebase real time Database? I was reading about that, but I’m not sure if it is the best choice. Firebase is more about chat or something where the is an interaction between different users.

Answer (score 0):

```
Couchbase-Lite-Android is a lightweight embedded NoSQL database engine for Android with the built-in ability to sync to Couchbase Server on the backend.

Couchbase Lite databases are able to sync with each other via Sync Gateway backed by Couchbase Server.

Other ways to setup replication:

No replication -- just local data store.
Peer-to-peer replication between Couchbase Lite instances.
Replication to multiple Sync Gateway instances rather than a single Sync Gateway.
```

#### https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android

#### Official Documentation for the latest release

#### https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/index.html

## For Android

#### https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/training/index.html?language=android

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think this is will be helpful to me for the next "level" of the app

Comment: @Mark. I think there is a more fundamental question that you have to answer. Is your data model suited for relational style table schema or if it is non-relational in nature. You can then determine if you want to use SQLite and use ORM wrappers or go NoSQL (like Couchbase Lite or Firebase). Here is a link that may help you with your decision- [SQL versus NoSQL](https://blog.couchbase.com/comparison-sql-nosql-simplify-database-decision/)

Comment: @rajagp. Thank you for the answer. I've read what you linked me and to be honest I didn't think about the data model. I tried for now with Firebase. Can you help me in understanding what is better?

Comment: @Mark.  It really depends on the application and type of data you are dealing with. If you looking at unstructured / semi-structured data or data that is likely to evolve significantly (requiring tedious schema migrations), then NoSQL is a better choice. I don't know much about your app but "Catalog" style data is typically a good use case for NoSQL . Here are some [examples](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2999856/big-data-business-intelligence/10-use-cases-where-nosql-will-outperform-sql.html).

Comment: @rajagp I can tell you how the app is organised and also the "database". The collection contains Cards, which are divided into categories. Each user can see the whole collection and check if he/she has it or not. This allows the user to create his/her own catalogue. I tried with Firebase real-time database, is it a good idea?